# Receiving a `r' Fatal Error when trying to build basic Ada code

Tags: ada

I have had a new error show up on MacOS (intel x86) using the native AdaCore GNAT2019 toolchain.

```
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: invalid option `r'
gprbuild:: *** compilation phase failed
```

My code is:

```
procedure Main is
    A : Float;
begin
    A := 1.0;
end Main;
```

When I run or build, I get this error:

```
gprbuild -d -P</path to default.gpr> </path to main.adb>
Compile
    [Ada]       main.adb
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: invalid option `r'
gprbuild:: *** compilation phase failed
[2024-01-18 11:13:47] process exited with status 4, elapsed time 0.94s
```

Pretty basic code but I have no idea how to locate that error.  It does this with EVERY program now, even when Main just includes a "null".

I did some pretty heavy google searching and could only find some very old posts that don't really show the same error.  I'm using CE2019, GPS, and I have XCode installed with XCode CLI.  I've deleted the entirety of the path/GNAT/2019 folder and reinstalled completely.

Anyone know how to rectify this?  What did I change that made this show up?

Comment: See also these later [releases](https://github.com/simonjwright/distributing-gcc).